# Applying ST_Intersects in a query with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS materialized view (`study_region_all`) with stream lines and a table of county boundary polygons (`counties`). They both have a column called `co_fips` but for a subset of items in the study_regions_all MV, the co_fips values are wrong and need to be replaced with the co_fips value from the counties that those stream lines are in. Previously, I had done this in Python using `arcpy.Intersect_Analysis()`. I know I can use `ST_Intersects` from PostGIS in a similar manner but I am not quite sure how to set the query up correctly. This is the query to get my first subset (before intersecting stream lines and county boundaries):

```
SELECT co_fips 
FROM data.study_regions_all
WHERE SUBSTRING(reach_id ,1,2) = ANY(ARRAY['60', '66', '72' ,'78']);
```

How would I apply ST_Intersects (or another function) to this query to get the `county co_fips` to replace the `co_fips` for the corresponding stream lines that fall within the county boundaries?

Comment: You can't UPDATE a materialized view, except from its sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. The generalized goal is to [coalesce](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/) geometries A and B based on a condition.

I'll assume you know the IDs of the features you need to have fixed and that all rows in `study_region_all` have values in the geom field.

In that case, you can do:

```
WITH needsfixing as (
SELECT 
a.id,
b.geom
FROM
study_regions_all a
INNER JOIN counties b on ST_INTERSECTS(a.geom,b.geom) is True
--(alternate syntax: from a,b where ST_INTERSECTS(a.geom,b.geom))
WHERE a.id in (###list the ids for bad features###)
)

SELECT c.id,coalesce(d.geom,c.geom) as geom
FROM study_regions_all c
LEFT JOIN needsfixing d ON c.id = d.id
```

The CTE gives you the `counties` geometries where `study_region_all` geometries are problematic based on your list of ids, and the following query coalesces the fixed geometries with the valid geometries.

Comment: OK, this was the correct solution. I had to make a few tweaks but `COALESCE` and `LEFT JOIN` worked!

Comment: Great to hear @gwydion93. I just typed this out without running and testing it, so I'm sure there's a syntax error somewhere. Feel free to update the answer.